# How to insert autocomplete templates in monodevelop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, autocomplete, monodevelop

I am using Monodevelop-Unity  (5.9.6) for my game on  OS X ElCaptain.

In OSX, Monodevelop editor can popup autocompletion template whenever pressing ctr + space as shown in the image. [image: Monodevelop autocomplete template].

However there seems no way to select the template and insert on the code. Note we can manually insert the template using Edit>Insert template....

Please advice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio I am able to add a template after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key **two times**

For example, write `for` and then presssed two times <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME55ToWSHP8).

Comment: OK, Same here in mono-develop, missed some how